# Finally behaves different in SF compared to java

Tags: apex

I was under the assumption that the finally code block of the `try/catch/finally` always gets invoked irrespective of an uncaught `exception/caught exception/no exception` thrown in the `try block,finally` always gets executed in java, but in SF,i just experienced that finally doesn't get invoked when an uncaught exception is thrown.

Can anybody throw light on this please?

Comment: i don't think so. it would be great if you can put some example with this question.

Comment: If an exception is "Uncaught" then how would you expect the Finally to execute as by your statement it was uncaught thus never in the try/catch/finally block - Maybe add an example to show what you are talking about

Comment: @Eric It actually works the same as it does in Java; you have to actually read the logs to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @sfdcfox - So you are saying that a finally block will execute if an uncaught exception occurs outside of the try/catch block?

Comment: @Eric the finally for a try block will execute without a catch block in the middle. However, the exception will still bubble up the stack until it's handled. This mechanism allows you to defer an exception to a higher handler while still performing some clean-up (e.g. saving a record). Maybe you should take a peek at my answer if that'll help clarify things.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks for the answer (was not there when I commented or I did not see it lol)

Comment: @sfdcfox - My interp of the Question though was that the exception was thrown outside of the try block that contained the finally thus why the finally never happened (unless of course it bubbled up) but that is why I asked to see the code all depends on order of events

Comment: @Eric I'm pretty sure that *not* catching an exception is not explained very well in the documentation. Up until a few weeks ago, I've never known that you could try-finally without a catch (I've never had a use for it), or what would happen if your catch didn't match the exception. I think the hint for me was "thrown in the try block." Half of the fun answering on this forum is figuring out what someone's even talking about.

Answer (score 6):

It behaves identically to Java. Here's my example code:

```
try {
    Integer x = (Integer)null + 5;
} finally {
    System.debug('Here I am');
}
```

Here's the log file for this:

```
14:48:22.023 (23371012)|EXECUTION_STARTED
14:48:22.023 (23385329)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
14:48:22.024 (24334530)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|Here I am
14:48:22.024 (24474224)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

In short, if you fail to catch it, your finally still executes, but your transaction will still be rolled back if the exception is not handled by the time it reaches the top of the execution stack. Here's a further example:

```
try {
    try {
        Integer x = (Integer)null + 5;
    } finally {
        System.debug('Here I am');
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception caught: '+e);
}
```

Here, the outer catch actually handles the exception, while the inner one still has its finally block executed:

```
14:50:03.021 (21452170)|EXECUTION_STARTED
14:50:03.021 (21461457)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
14:50:03.021 (21946912)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|Here I am
14:50:03.022 (22063251)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Exception caught: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
14:50:03.022 (22111338)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
14:50:03.023 (23260562)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Semantically, try-finally is basically the same as the following construct:

```
try {
    try {
        Integer x = (Integer)null + 5;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Here I am');
        throw e;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception caught: '+e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!. The logic behind all this (examples) is what is needed to understand a lot of what is going on. Difference between book smart and street smart. Glad we have you on here contributing!

Comment: @sfdcfox, you are right! i can see the debug message from the finally in the logs, i always believed that the finally code always gets invoked irrespective of a caught/uncaught exception, but a statement from the latest salesforce apex dev guide(winter 16,the last sentence on the page 525) confused me which says:
When exceptions are uncatchable, catch blocks, as well as finally blocks if any, aren’t executed.

Comment: @ShaliniMendu It's true that if you blow a *governor limit*, your code ceases *immediately*, which doesn't matter, because your entire transaction will be rolled back. They're not "lying," they're just omitting the fact that, assuming your code does not hit a governor limit, finally blocks behave identically to how they do in Java.

Comment: @sfdcfox, i am sure they do not intend to lie, but that sentence read on its own is confusing and suggests otherwise, anyway, thanks for the clarification, it is relieving to know that certain basic concepts of java remain the same :) with SF too..

Answer (score 1):

if you check this https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

```
try{
     //Your code here
} catch (ListException e) {
     //Optional catch of a specific exception type
     //Specific exception handling code here
} catch (Exception e) {
     //Generic exception handling code here
} finally {
     //optional finally block
     //code to run whether there is an exception or not
}
```

**finally code to run whether there is an exception or not**

---

Execute below code in developer console

```
integer i =0;

try{
    Integer j = 1/0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    system.debug('=====exception===');
} finally {
    i++;
}
system.debug('=====i===='+i);
```

You can see the **i** value is incremented to **1**
[image]

```
integer i =0; 
try{ 
    i++; 
} 
finally { 
    System.debug('i run always'); 
}
```

Comment: integer i =0;

try{
    Integer j = 1/0;
}  finally {
    System.debug('i run always');
} I was expecting to see the debug statement 'i run always'.

Comment: where is your catch statement ? you can't execute this in dev console. It will give match exception

Comment: try this code `integer i =0; 
try{ 
    Integer j = 0; 
} 
finally { 
    System.debug('i run always'); 
}`

Comment: When i run the code i printed in the dev console,It displayed 'System MathException: Divide by 0'. I was expecting the finally message 'i run always' to be printed along with the exception

Comment: yes @ShaliniMendu that's why you need catch block here. if any exception occur it will execute `catch` block then after `finally` block

Comment: @Ratan You'll get an exception, but it will still appear in the logs. try-finally has the exact same syntax and behavior as in Java.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes. I doesn't matter if exception occurs or not. In debug we will get the `finally` block value.